# Unable to reference DAL project from BLL after separating POCO classes

Tags: c#, entity-framework, assembly-references

I have a BLL and DAL projects in my solution in addition to my web application project. I'm using entity framework 5 and i had the .tt file within the DAL project. Everything was working fine but then i tried separating the .tt file into a new project "Entities" based on [this](http://nullablecode.com/2013/09/splitting-entity-framework-model-classes-separate-projects/) link.

The Entities and DAL projects build fine. But for all the classes in my BLL that has "using DAL", I have a new error "The type or namespace DAL cannot be found". I tried cleaning all solutions and rebuilding them in order, I also tried removing the DAL reference from the BLL project and readding it but still the same error.

What could be causing this problem? What more information i can add to help finding out what the issue is ?

[image]

EDIT:

Here's an example of a generated POCO class

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//    This code was generated from a template.
//
//    Manual changes to this file may cause unexpected behavior in your application.
//    Manual changes to this file will be overwritten if the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

namespace Entities
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class tblsource_type
    {
        public tblsource_type()
        {
            this.tbltitles = new HashSet<tbltitle>();
        }

        public int Source_Type_Id { get; set; }
        public string Source_Type_Name { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<tbltitle> tbltitles { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: have you checked the build order and dependencies? Are the classes generated and become part of the DAL project?

Comment: Can you show us how a class of your DAL dll looks like? Including the namespace

Comment: Did you make sure that  the new project use the same .NET version ?

Comment: @Jaster yes I made sure I build them in the correct order. The POCO classes are generated fine and I referenced the new tt file from within the DAL edms

Comment: @Juan Please check my updated question. I don't have any cs files in my DAL.

Comment: @EmmanuelM. Yes they are all targeting 4.5 version

Comment: So do you need the `using DAL;` code? Do your TT generate POCO classes under that namespace? Can we see the generated classes code?

Comment: @Juan thank you for your help. I was trying to let the old code (using DAL) to work, although I no longer need it. I removed the reference and it's working fine now. I appreciate your time.

Comment: Ok, I have added an answer for this. Glad it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you no longer need the `using DAL;` statement as you don't have anything any more on that namespace. Just remove it and should be fine.